# Dynamic variable in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, variables, dynamic

I need to pass a variable by name like this

```
Dim html_news = "...the news ..."
Dim var = "news"
Dim a = "html_" & var
' content of that variable
```

How can I do that in VB.NET ?

Comment: *Why* do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vb.net doesn't really lend itself to what you need to do - you could have done that sort  of thing in scripting languages like classic asp and JavaScript. Although it might not have been the 'right' way to do it - the use of the 'eval' function is frowned on in Javscript as it's a security risk. I think the code below will do what you need in a way that's more in keeping with the way that vb.net works  -

```
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
Dim html_news = "...the news ..."
d.Add("html_news","...the news ...")
Dim var = "news"
Dim a = d("html_" & var)
```